# it adds an extra line below first column of the table. Why?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Eigenvalues of Study System with and without SSSC}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
        \toprule 
        \multirow{3}{*}{Mode}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{75\% Compensation level}\\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{case:1(without SSSC)} &\multicolumn{2}{|c}{case:2(with SSSC)} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$  \\
        \midrule 
        Supersynnchronous&-9.5903$\pm$629.17i&0.01524 &-12.344$\pm$556.39i&0.02218\\
        Subsynnchronous&1.6034$\pm$123.7   &-0.01296&-9.0587$\pm$137.23i&0.06586\\ 
        Shaft    &-0.4911$\pm$6.1496i&0.07962  &-0.48842$\pm$6.1493i&0.07917\\
        Torsional &-85.88 $\pm$38.471i&0.91261  &-85.883$\pm$37.936i&0.91474\\
        Electromechanical&-11.602$\pm$91.825i&0.12535  &-9.6224$\pm$94.729i&0.10106\\ 
        \midrule
        \multirow{7}{*}{Other}&-2416.6$\pm$1271.4i&0.88511  &-2421.1$\pm$1252.1i&0.88825\\
        &      0$\pm$0i     &  -      &-2670.3            &1      \\ 
        &   0$\pm$0i        &   -     &-110.25            &1      \\
        &      -0.12579     &    1    &-0.15132           &1      \\
        &     -0.0035219    &   1     &-0.0034435         &1      \\
        &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-      \\ 
        &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-      \\                  
        \bottomrule 
        \label{comparison75}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `\label` command is inside of the `tabular`. If you put it in the scope of `table` then the extra line disappears.

I am not fully sure why this exact problem occurs, probably the `\label` command is seen as the start of an extra row for which the first column separator line is printed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Eigenvalues of Study System with and without SSSC}
    \label{comparison75}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
        \toprule 
        \multirow{3}{*}{Mode}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{75\% Compensation level}\\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{case:1(without SSSC)} &\multicolumn{2}{|c}{case:2(with SSSC)} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$ &$\sigma\pm j\omega$& $\zeta$  \\
        \midrule 
        Supersynnchronous&-9.5903$\pm$629.17i&0.01524 &-12.344$\pm$556.39i&0.02218\\
        Subsynnchronous&1.6034$\pm$123.7   &-0.01296&-9.0587$\pm$137.23i&0.06586\\ 
        Shaft    &-0.4911$\pm$6.1496i&0.07962  &-0.48842$\pm$6.1493i&0.07917\\
        Torsional &-85.88 $\pm$38.471i&0.91261  &-85.883$\pm$37.936i&0.91474\\
        Electromechanical&-11.602$\pm$91.825i&0.12535  &-9.6224$\pm$94.729i&0.10106\\ 
        \midrule
        \multirow{7}{*}{Other}&-2416.6$\pm$1271.4i&0.88511  &-2421.1$\pm$1252.1i&0.88825\\
        &      0$\pm$0i     &  -      &-2670.3            &1      \\ 
        &   0$\pm$0i        &   -     &-110.25            &1      \\
        &      -0.12579     &    1    &-0.15132           &1      \\
        &     -0.0035219    &   1     &-0.0034435         &1      \\
        &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-      \\ 
        &                   &         &0$\pm$0i           &-      \\                  
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It solved error.. thank you...